# React native todo application

Tags: react-native

I need your help. Now I'm trying to create a todo application.I will try to make an application on the logic of pure react.The problem is that when I start typing input, I get an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.value)`.Please help me with this task. I will be very grateful to you

Tasks.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";
import Task_Item from "./Task_Item";
import Form from "./Form";

export default function Tasks() {

const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

let addTask = (myInput) => {
    if (myInput) {
        let newTask = {
            id: Date.now(),
            name: myInput
        }
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask])
    }
}

let handleInput = (e) => {
    setTasks(e.target.value)
}

return (<View style={styles.all_list}>

<FlatList data={tasks}
              renderItem={({item}) => (<Task_Item keyExtractor={item => item.id} el={item}/>)}
    />
<Form addTask={addTask} inputValue={handleInput}/>
</View>)
}
```

Task_item.js

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, Text, ScrollView} from "react-native";

export default function Task_Item({el}) {
return (<ScrollView>
        <TouchableHighlight>
    <Text>{el.name}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </ScrollView>)
}
```

Form.js

```
import React from "react";
import {KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput} from "react-native";

export default function Form({inputValue, addTask}) {
return (<KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <TextInput
        placeholder='Type Text...'
        onChangeText={inputValue}
    />
    <Text
        onPress={addTask}
    >+</Text>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>)
}
```

Comment: Firstable read documentation react native and forms, learn input onchange methods

Answer (score 0):

I see two things you could improve.
The `onChangeText` method directly passes you the text, so you should either pass the `setInput` to your `inputValue` Form prop, either change the `onChangeText` to the `onChange`.

Using `onChangeText`

Tasks

```js
<Form addTask={addTask} inputValue={setInput} />
```

Form.js

```js
<TextInput placeholder="..." onChangeText={inputValue} />
```

And therefore you can delete the `handleInput` method.

with `onChange`

Tasks

```js
<Form addTask={addTask} inputValue={handleInput} />
```

Form.js

```js
<TextInput placeholder="..." onChange={handleInput} />
```

---

The second thing is that you `handleInput` method is changing your `tasks` and not your `input`...

```js
const handleInput = (e) => setInput(e.target.value)
```

---

Your `addTask` is not getting the input... You could change your method to this:

```js
const addTask = () => {
  if (input) setTasks([...tasks, { id: Date.now(), name: input }])
}
```